# Hide Group of controls in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.NET project form with employee details have fourteen label boxes, five text boxes, four masked text boxes, two combo boxes, two radio buttons, one rich text boxes and two buttons. I want to hide these items when form is load. I try with

```
.Visible = False
```

method. But it is a long code.. How i hide these items in a simple code?

Comment: I'd just write a subroutine that accepts a boolean value, place all the ".visible=booleanValue" in the subroutine, then call this subroutine to change the visibility state.

Comment: just marked this answered if this is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
put those controls in a GroupBox2 and set its visible property to false.

[image]

When your application runs, GroupBox is not visible so i use a button captioned "Show GroupBox2" so When i clicked the button, GroupBox2 will be visible:

[image]

Source code for making the GroupBox Visible

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GroupBox2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: All these controls in a Group Box named EMPGBDATA

Comment: yea.. but i need group box visible. I need to hide only the controls.. Is there any chance??

Comment: put inside your groupbox in another groupbox,

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Panel` which contains all those controls (label,txtbox,combobox etc.,) and set the .visible property on the panel as false. In this case , you do not have to set the .visible for each and every control.

Answer (score 0):

you could put them to a panel, then you only need set the visible of panel